# Missing link in proof of quadratic reciprocity law

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

I am trying to figure out the proof of the quadratic reciprocity law in Serre's book A Course in Arithmetic. I think my question is possible to answer independent of the book though:

Let $l$ and $p$ be two distinct prime numbers. Let $\Omega$ be an algebraic closure of $F_p$, and let $w \in \Omega$ be a primitive $l$-th root of unity. 
At the end of lemma 1 Serre writes that 
\begin{equation}
l-1-\sum\limits_{u\in F_l^*}w^u =l \end{equation}. 
This suggests that: 
\begin{equation} 
\sum\limits_{u\in F_l}w^u=0
\end{equation}

This is supposed to be obvious since Serre just says it like this, but I don't see it! Thank you!

Comment: what is $l$? Is it same as $p$?

Comment: If you multiply by $w$, then you permute the terms but do not change any. So the value of the sum does not change. Since $w \neq 1$, this means the sum is $0$.

Comment: I edited it Praphulla, thank you. And I think it answers my question mixedmath, thanks!!